# How to avoid providing a dummy Vue data structure during initialization?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue-driven HTML I have the line

```
<span>Last updated on {{incident.LastUpdate[0].date}}</span>
```

`data` in the `Vue` instance is defined as

```
data: {
    incident: {}
}
```

In the course of the execution, `incident` is asynchonously loaded but during the initial page load I see

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
(...)
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

This is understandable because the `incident` contents are not available yet. When they are abvailable, the page is displayed correctly. The error is therefore predictibe and temporary so I could just forget it.

I wanted however to silence it and initialized `incident` with some dummy data

```
data: {
        incident: {
            LastUpdate: [
                {
                    date: null
                }
            ]
        },
    },
```

The error is now gone but I feel that this is awkward way to solve it. It can also become cumbersome if there is a more data to initialize.

**My question: what is the correct way to handle this problem in Vue? Dummy data as in my fix?**

Comment: I seen the same behavior in some other frameworks, even if just for a very short time but does really get noticeable when pages are loading slow..

Comment: I usually wrap the content that is wainting some async data with a `<span v-if="incident != null">`, or another flag, that determines whether show or not some data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Declare an empty array. it will help other developers to understand
  the structure of your data upfront
- Keep your Markup logic-less as possible. use Computed method to retrieve the first value, with error handling.

see the code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Last updated on {{lastUpdatedTime}}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            incident: {
                lastUpdate:[]
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        lastUpdatedTime () {
            if (this.incident.LastUpdate.length === 0) return '' // think about a default please :)
            return this.incident.LastUpdate[0].date
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: These are good points, thanks. Especially the second one is a neat fix (and overall a good approach indeed).